# Combining distinct patient ID with patient characteristics

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to use Excel to analyse a large set of patient data (>16,000 entries). Each patient is identified by a numeric patient identifier and is recorded each visit. This means some patients are only represented once in this database, whereas others appear over 10 times.

Right now, I'm trying to figure out a way to combine patient ID with patient sex, so that each patient only counts once. Later on, I would like to do the same thing with different age groups, primarily under and above 18 years.

It basically looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I work for a private healthcare and we pull data like this on a daily basis. You're playing with a huge amount of entries, I highly recommend using Access Database rather than Excel. We use Access Database and we can pull off reports etc. For example, if I want to see how many patients have been seen in 2015, I can do so with Access Database. Also, using Access Database will solve your question.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I've imported the database into access, which seems to work fine. I've never worked with access before, but I suppose this is a quick way to learn. Thanks again

Comment: No worries. It took me a while to get my head round things in Access. Use this to help you get started. https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Access-2013-training-courses-videos-and-tutorials-a4bd10ea-d5f4-40c5-8b37-d254561f8bce

Answer (score 0):

Purging duplicates from a data set like this to give unique entries can be done in Excel using the   Data  =>  Remove Duplicates   option in the ribbon.  Multiple fields (even all fields) in the selected range/table can be selected.  Below is a generic sample how it might look.

To analyse different age groups I would recommend using a "helper column" with a formula to flag entries according to the desired criteria.  e.g. `=IF(D4<18,"< 18 y.o.",">= 18 y.o.")` then create a pivot-table, display the results in table format and filter the pivot-table by the helper column.

[image]